# Search with multiple key words

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

In my application I am using **asp.net, c#, jquery** and I've a requirement as per bellow :

I've a xml file "Mobile.xml" which contents is as per bellow :

```
<Mobiles>
  <Mobile Id="1">
    <MDetails ModelNo="1" Desc="x phone color red"/>
    <MDetails ModelNo="2" Desc="x phone color green"/>
    <MDetails ModelNo="3" Desc="x phone color blue"/>
    <MDetails ModelNo="4" Desc="x phone color black"/>
    <MDetails ModelNo="5" Desc="x phone color yellow"/>
    <MDetails ModelNo="6" Desc="x phone color pink"/>
    <MDetails ModelNo="7" Desc="x phone color gray"/>
    <MDetails ModelNo="8" Desc="x phone color silver"/>
    <MDetails ModelNo="9" Desc="x phone color orange"/>
  </Mobile>
  <Mobile Id="2">
    <MDetails ModelNo="11" Desc="y phone color red"/>
    <MDetails ModelNo="12" Desc="y phone color green"/>
    <MDetails ModelNo="13" Desc="y phone color blue"/>
    <MDetails ModelNo="14" Desc="y phone color black"/>
    <MDetails ModelNo="15" Desc="y phone color yellow"/>
    <MDetails ModelNo="16" Desc="y phone color pink"/>
    <MDetails ModelNo="17" Desc="y phone color gray"/>
    <MDetails ModelNo="18" Desc="y phone color silver"/>
    <MDetails ModelNo="19" Desc="y phone color orange"/>
  </Mobile>
  <Mobile Id="3">
  ......
  <Mobile>
  ......
</Mobiles>
```

And I *want to fetch the details of all tags* **with respect to multiple *key words*** where keywords will get from a input search string.

Like if search string is **"x phone color red green"** then it should return the details of the tags :

```
<MDetails ModelNo="1" Desc="x phone color red"/>
<MDetails ModelNo="2" Desc="x phone color green"/>
```

And if the search string will be : **"phone color red green"** then it should return:

```
<MDetails ModelNo="1" Desc="x phone color red"/>
<MDetails ModelNo="2" Desc="x phone color green"/>
<MDetails ModelNo="11" Desc="y phone color red"/>
<MDetails ModelNo="12" Desc="y phone color green"/>
```

I tried the bellow code which is not enough :

```
public void doSearch(string strSearchContent)
{
    string[] strArrSearchContents;
    strArrSearchContents = strSearchContent.Split(' ');

    string fileName = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~\XMLFiles/Mobile.xml");
    XDocument doc = null;
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(fileName))
        {
            doc = XDocument.Load(fileName);

            IEnumerable<XElement> list1 =
                from elements in doc.Descendants("MDetails")
                where
                    elements.Attribute("Desc").Value.Trim().ToLower().Contains(strArrSearchContents[0]) &&
                    elements.Attribute("Desc").Value.Trim().ToLower().Contains(strArrSearchContents[1]) &&
                    elements.Attribute("Desc").Value.Trim().ToLower().Contains(strArrSearchContents[2]) &&
                    elements.Attribute("Desc").Value.Trim().ToLower().Contains(strArrSearchContents[3]) &&
                    elements.Attribute("Desc").Value.Trim().ToLower().Contains(strArrSearchContents[4])
                select elements;

        }
}
```

The above code is not at all the solution for this type of searching...
but I've described my requirement.

Comment: I think you can spit your search keywords into two parts.and then start searching?

Comment: `i tried the bellow code which is not enough` - Why not?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote something a bit more generically but I think you can use it.  Basically, it is a linq query that says: for each word in the description, make sure it is contained in the list of things to find.

```
string toFind = "x phone color red green";
string[] toFindStuff = toFind.Split(' ');
List<string> desc = new List<string>{ "x phone color red", "y phone color green", "x phone color blue", "x phone color green"};
List<string> filtered = desc.Where(x => x.Split(' ').All(y => toFindStuff.Contains(y))).ToList();
```

result:

```
List<String> (2 items) 
x phone color red 
x phone color green
```

Comment: @pks if this worked for you, please "accept" my answer by hitting the check